# Cannot make Android In-App purchase using test account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In-App purchase in my app. I am able to create different In-App products along with test accounts. But the problem occurs when I purchase In-App product, it shows a message "The item you were trying to purchase could not be found". But the item is existing with exact product id. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Is the purchase item marked as published? If it isn't you may get that exception.

Take a look at [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real). Step 2 talks about marking items as published. You also have to ensure the application is signed with your release certificate.

Answer (score 0):

try doing it without test account, it will work best luck :)

Comment: Then how do you test in-app purchasing?